# This pretty little jQuery code seems to not work.. anyone know why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

If I run it. It returns no errors. And in firebug it does in fact select the proper elements in the DOM.

If I break it apart and do something like this :

```
$('img[hspace]').css('marginLeft', ($('img[hspace]').attr('hspace') / 2) + 'px')
```

That works.

Here's the monster in its entirety.

```
$('img[hspace]').each(function(el){
    var pixels = parseInt($(el).attr('hspace'));
    if(isNaN(pixels) || pixels < 1)
        pixels = 0;
    else
        pixels = pixels / 2;
    $(el).css('marginLeft', pixels + 'px')
         .css('marginRight', pixels + 'px')
         .removeAttr('hspace');
});
```

**Update**

My HTML :

```
 `<div class='grid_7'>
        <p><p>
            this is mys</p>
        <p>
            <img align="left" alt="dude its me" border="10" height="168" hspace="30" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/hq-photo/root/system/photos/6187/resized_orig/photo.jpg" vspace="10" width="130" /></p>
        <p>
            this is as good as it gets</p>

        <p>
            this isasd</p>
        <p>
            sdfasdfasdfasdfasd</p>
        <p>
            asdfasdfasdf</p>
        <p>

            asdfa</p>
        <p>
            sdfasdfasdf</p>
        <p>
            &nbsp;</p>
        <p>
            &nbsp;</p>
        <p>

            &nbsp;</p>
        <p>
            &nbsp;</p>
        <p>
            &nbsp;</p>
        <p>
            <img align="right" alt="it's also me" border="50" height="168" hspace="50" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/hq-photo/root/system/photos/6187/resized_orig/photo.jpg" vspace="50" width="130" /></p></p>
      </div>`
```

Comment: try changing $(el) to $(this)

Comment: I'd recommend passing a radix to `parseInt` too for unambiguity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The each function [passes in the index as the first parameter, not the element](http://api.jquery.com/each/).  You probably want to do `$(this)` rather than `$(el)`.

Comment: Or - `function(idx, el) { }` should do the trick too... http://api.jquery.com/each

Comment: Interesting. In my example that I'm working with, the `this` didn't work, but the `(idx, el)` did. And by work, I just mean it passed without error. But no actual changes were made to my DOM. Anyone have any idea why? The content that I'm parsing is coming out of a WYSIYWYG so there's a lot of `/n` 's all around. Again if I just run this without a loop, it'll at least target one and move it successfully.

Answer (score 4):

`el` references the index of the element in the collection and not the element. Either

- add a second parameter to the function, this will be the element.
- use `this` inside of the function. `this` references the element